# I can't get code to post in a question - it "appears" there is unformatted code but there is not

Tags: markdown

I have spent almost two hours creating a new question, trying to provide helpful information and code - I couldn't use a code sandbox because sqlalchemy and flask are not available on codesandbox.com as dependencies.

When I get to the "review" step of my post, I get an error that says:

> Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

Of course the key word here is "appears".  There are about a half-dozen code blocks but they're all formatted correctly.  I've tried using three tick fences, tried using control-k to format the 4 spaces, tried using both methods together, and I keep getting the error.  There's not enough detail in the error to tell exactly where the stackoverflow code thinks there is unformatted code.

Any suggestions on how to get past this error?

Comment: It took me less time to solve the problem than drafting the problem on StackOverflow, because of this "code block" error.

Answer (score 12):

Solution was that there was an error message that I put in a blockquote - after all, it wasn't code; it was an error message.  The stackoverflow code interpreted the error message as code.  I changed it from a blockquote block to a code block and it appears I could post the message now - but now I'm up against a limit that I can only post once in 90 minutes so this question is blocking me from posting the real question.

Just a suggestion to the admins: blockquoted segments should not be checked by the code validator.

Comment: FWIW suggestions about the workings of the site are better suited for the [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Related to OP's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63700169/5538420), it is also possible to format code blocks *inside* a blockquote.

For example:

````
> ```
> > code
> * errors
> - logs
> ```
````

gets rendered as:

> ```
> > code
> * errors
> - logs
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I lost hours searching and trying many ways. However, couldn't correct it.

Finally, I tried adding a small block of content.
After the first submission, we can keep updating it block by block to identify the exact block of content responsible for the issue.

Once identified, try to fix it by adding one by one line or making it a list.

Try this approach if none of the solution is working for you.

In my case, I had entered as below:

**E.g. 120.1 => 120.00
120.9 => 121.00**

This was getting interpreted as code while it was just a sample input/output.

After making this as a list below, it resolved for me.
E.g.

1. 120.1 => 120.00
2. 120.9 => 121.00

Hope it would help someone.

Answer (score 1):

Another false positive is that a table **a little** like this

| Row Index | Expected Cols | Example |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | `rowIndex+1=1` | 2 |
| 1 | `rowIndex+1=2` | 4 5 |
| 2 | `rowIndex+1=3` | 2 5 8 |

was triggering the parser to think I was entering code.

Of course I cannot post exactly the "faulty" text.  To get this to submit here I put a back-ticks around
rowIndex+1=1

Answer (score 1):

I'm also get this error. There's only need to do is that block your codes order by order and press CTRL + K. Successful!

Answer (score 0):

I agree it is very time consuming process but there is option you should give 4 space to every line of code. some one suggested for tool even but I do not think there any tool for posting question without getting formatting error in code part.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you put your code in these braces [''' your code'''] instead of this ['your code']